# Hiding sub view in Stackview adds extra space

Tags: ios, hide, whitespace, uistackview, spacing

I have an app with a horizontal stackview which contains 3 UIViews.

When all 3 UIViews are visible it works fine like this:

[image]

However if I hide one of the UIViews dynamically like this a space is added in the stackview between the 2 UIViews:

```
secondView.isHidden = true
```

[image]

How can I get rid of the extra space? In Xcode I have the stack view's spacing set to 0. I don't know how to solve this. Please let me know if you know how to solve this.

Comment: Please share your code that you tried.

Comment: Is `Distribution` set to `Fill Equally`? Have you set any constraints on the *subviews*, or only on the stack view itself?

Comment: @DonMag yes the distribution is set to fill equally. I have set the height constraint for each subview.

Comment: @es1 - well, something else is going on then... Are you adding the stack view and arrangedSubviews in Storyboard or via code?

Comment: @DonMag I am adding the stackview in the Storyboard. It is strange I removed the entire stack view and did it with a UIView containing all the 3 UIViews instead. However I am getting the same issue. It has something to to with the updating of UIViews. The background color is not being stretched out to the full width I found out. What could be the reason? I tried setNeedsDisplay() and layoutIfNeeded(). Still no luck.

Comment: @es1 -- are your subviews "custom" views, using layers for their background by chance?

Comment: @DonMag the background colours are set in the Interface Builder. I have no code for setting the background.

Comment: @es1 - we'll need to see any other code you have that could be affecting things. Take a look at this: https://pastebin.com/w2pRYNqS ... when run, it will look similar to the images you posted... tap anywhere to toggle `.isHidden` property on the center view.