# UIView background color not updated after setting width constraint dynamically

Tags: ios, dynamic, uiview, constraints, background-color

I have 3 UIViews next to each other.
Sometimes I have to dynamically hide some of the UIViews and adjust the width constraints of the remaining UIViews so that they fill up the remaining horizontal space.

I have IBOutlets to the width constraints of each UIView.

I dynamically change the width constraints.
For example like this:

```
if(secondView.isHidden == false && thirdView.isHidden == false){
      let topViewIconsWidth = (self.bounds.width - 4)/3
      firstViewWidthConstraint.constant = topViewIconsWidth
      secondViewWidthConstraint.constant = topViewIconsWidth
      thirdViewWidthConstraint.constant = topViewIconsWidth
    }
```

I then set the constraints to `active`:

```
  firstViewWidthConstraint.isActive = true
  secondViewWidthConstraint.isActive = true
  thirdViewWidthConstraint.isActive = true
```

I then call `setNeedsDisplay` like this:

```
      secondView.setNeedsDisplay()
      thirdView.setNeedsDisplay()
      secondView.setNeedsDisplay()
```

I even have the entire code block wrapped inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async {`

However I still get something like this:

[image]

As you can see there is a white space between the green UIView and the image on the right. I want to close this gap.

In the Hierarchy Debugger I see that the UIView's background color does not stretch to its entire width:

[image]

Comment: How are you drawing the background? `myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.myColor`? Or are you overriding `drawRect`? Setting the `backgroundColor` of the view's layer?

Comment: The background colour is set in the Interface Builder.

Comment: You should show all of the code for setting the width constraints? Where is that code located? In a `UIView` subclass? What function?

Comment: @es1 - please don't post duplicate questions... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74276917/hiding-sub-view-in-stackview-adds-extra-space

Comment: @DonMag these are 2 different questions. One is with a stack view and the other without a stack view.

Comment: @es1 - I'm pretty sure it's the same problem. Based on your Debug Hierarchy screen-shot, it looks like the "Green" is either a `CAShapeLayer` or a masked layer?